# Which IP does a call from angular use for backend call?

Tags: java, angular, server, ip

Maybe that's a easy question (I am sure it is). But I couldn't find an answer yet.
My Angular frontend and Java Backend are running on the same server, with the same domain.
From witch IP is the Backend called by the frontend? The server ip? Or the client ip of the user?
Thanks!!

Comment: The client communicates with angular. Angular communicates with the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frontend is only **hosted** by your server. It is then **downloaded and executed by the browser** of your customers. Hence the IP will be the one from where your customer's browser executes the calls to your backend. **Your customer's IP**.

Comment: you're welcome. could you mark my answer as "accepted" then please? :)